# Cannot implicitly convert type 'char*' to 'bool'

Tags: c#

The program below is from the book "Cracking the coding interview", by Gayle Laakmann McDowell.

The original code is written in C.

Here is the original code:

```
void reverse(char *str) {
    char * end = str;
    char tmp;
    if (str) {
        while (*end) {
            ++end;
        }
        --end;
        while (str < end) {
            tmp = *str; 
            *str++ = *end; 
            *end-- = tmp;  
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to convert it in C#.  After researching via Google and playing with the code, below is what I have.  I am a beginner and really stuck.  I am not getting the value I am expecting. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
class Program
{        
    unsafe void reverse(char *str)
    {
        char* end = str;
        char tmp;
        if (str) // Cannot implicitly convert type 'char*' to 'bool'
        { 
            while(*end) // Cannot implicitly convert type 'char*' to 'bool'
            {
                ++end;
            }
            --end;
            while(str < end)
            {
                tmp = *str;
                *str += *end;
                *end -= tmp;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: A C# beginnner and already trying to do unsafe code snippets?

Comment: If you are a beginner, why are you messing with pointers and unsafe code? Learn the basics first!!

Comment: I don't think that tell someone "do not do something!" is a good way of helping.

Comment: Yes. If you want to program in C, use C. If you want to learn C#, dive into the C# functions!

Comment: The compile error tells you *exactly* what's wrong with that code.

Comment: How I miss the days of coding with reckless abandon...

Answer (score 0):

C# is not like C in that you cannot use an integer value as an implicit bool. You need to manually convert it. One example:

```
if (str != 0)
while (*end != 0)
```

A word of warning: If you are migrating from C, there are a few things that can trip you up in a program like this. The main one is that `char` is 2 bytes. strings and chars are UTF-16 encoded. The C# equivalent of `char` is `byte`. Of course, you should use `string` rather than C-strings.

Another thing: If you got your `char*` by converting a normal `string` to a `char*`, forget your entire code. This is not C. Strings are not null-terminated.

Unless this is homework, you would much rather be doing something like this:

```
string foo = "Hello, World!";
string bar = foo.Reverse(); // bar now holds "!dlroW ,olleH";
```

Comment: C# strings aren't 0, null or '\0' terminated. So the while bit wouldn't work. I'm not aware of any method to make it work; I think the only way is by passing in the length as a parameter.

Comment: He's not using a string. I have no idea where he's getting his `char*`, but if it is a string, this isn't good.

Comment: @VladCiobanu, actually, strings in .Net *are* zero-terminated, but I think it's just an implementation detail and you shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: @KendallFrey, you also can't use a pointer as an implicit integer, so your `if` won't compile. It should be `if (str != null)`.

Comment: @KendallFrey, also, `string` doesn't actually have `Reverse()` method that would return a `string` (only an extension method that returns an `IEnumerable<char>`.

Comment: @svick: Where did you hear string are null-terminated? I thought they were length-specified, especially since they can contain '\0'. I'd like to see your source.

Comment: @KendallFrey, in practice, they are *both*. You can read about it for example [in an article from Jon Skeet](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx): “Although strings aren't null-terminated as far as the API is concerned, the character array is null-terminated, as this means it can be passed directly to unmanaged functions without any copying being involved, assuming the inter-op specifies that the string should be marshalled as Unicode.”

Comment: @svick: That's cool. I never knew that. I will have to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try making it more explicit what you are checking in the conditions:
  if(str != null)
  while(*end != '\0')

You might also want to watch out for that character swapping code: it looks like you've got a +/- in there.  If that's supposed to update your pointer positions, I'd suggest making those separate operations.

Comment: C# doesn't have `NULL`, but it does have `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really remember if this ever worked in C#, but I am quite certain it should not work now.

To start off by answering your question. There is no automatic cast between pointers and bool. You need to write

```
if(str != null)
```

Secondly, you can't convert char to bool. Moreover, there is no terminating character for C# strings, so you can't even implement this. Normally, you would write:

```
while(*end != '\0') // not correct, for illustration only
```

But there is no '\0' char, or any other magic-termination-char. So you will need to take an int param for length.

Going back to the big picture, this sort of code seems like a terribly inappropriate place to start learning C#. It's way too low level, few C# programmers deal with pointers, chars and unsafe contexts on a daily basis.

... and if you must know how to fix your current code, here's a working program:

```
unsafe public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var str = "Hello, World";
    fixed(char* chr = str){
    reverse(chr, str.Length);
    }
}

unsafe void  reverse(char *str, int length)
    {
        char* end = str;
        char tmp;
        if (str != null) //Cannot implicitly convert type 'char*' to 'bool'
        { 
        for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i) //Cannot implicitly convert type 'char*' to 'bool'
        {
            ++end;
        }
        --end;
            while(str<end)
            {
                tmp = *str;
                *str = *end;
                *end = tmp;
                --end;
                ++str;
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit: removed a couple of .Dump() calls, as I was trying it out in LINQPad :)

Comment: There *is* a `'\0'` character, but it isn't a terminating character. I'm guessing though, that in this case it would. This reeks of C-strings.

Answer (score 0):

As you discovered, you can use pointers in C#, if you use the `unsafe` keyword. But you should do that only when really necessary and when you really know what you're doing. You certainly shouldn't use pointers if you're just beginning with the language.

Now, to your actual question: you are given a string of characters and you want to reverse it. Strings in C# are represented as the `string` class. And `string` is immutable, so you can't modify it. But you can convert between a `string` and an array of characters (`char[]`) and you can modify that. And you can reverse an array by using [the static method `Array.Reverse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3877932.aspx). So, one way to write your method would be:

```
string Reverse(string str)
{
    if (str == null)
        return null;

    char[] array = str.ToCharArray();  // convert the string to array
    Array.Reverse(array);              // reverse the array
    string result = new string(array); // create a new string out of the array
    return result;                     // and return it
}
```

If you wanted to write the code that actually does the reversing, you can do that too (as an exercise, I wouldn't do it in production code):

```
string Reverse(string str)
{
    if (str == null)
        return null;

    char[] array = str.ToCharArray();

    // use indexes instead of pointers
    int start = 0;
    int end = array.Length - 1;

    while (start < end)
    {
        char tmp = array[start]; 
        array[start] = array[end];
        array[end] = tmp;
        start++;
        end--;
    }

    return new string(array);
}
```